# LINQ to objects vs for each - difference in execution timings

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I am having this For each loop

```
foreach (Account acct in acctTest)
            {
                if (acct.AccountId == acctId)
                {
                    foreach (Customer cust in acct.CustomerColl)
                    {
                        if (cust.CustomerId == custId)
                        {
                            customerName = cust.CustomerName;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Linq query which does similar stuff (think this can be improved)

```
customerName = (from acct in acctTest
                           where acct.AccountId == acctId
                           from cust in acct.CustomerColl
                           where cust.CustomerId == custId
                            select cust.CustomerName).ToString() ;
```

I execute the above two in a loop of 1000 times for 5 times,  get the execution timings as below.

Elapsed time for For Each ::: 7377
Elapsed time for Linq2 ::: 15653
Elapsed time for For Each ::: 1576
Elapsed time for Linq2 ::: 1718
Elapsed time for For Each ::: 1569
Elapsed time for Linq2 ::: 1726
Elapsed time for For Each ::: 1569
Elapsed time for Linq2 ::: 5583
Elapsed time for For Each ::: 1570
Elapsed time for Linq2 ::: 1506

why is there a difference and inconsistency in execution timings?
Also , is there a way the LINQ query can be rewritten for better performance?

Comment: You should use `FirstOrDefault`, not `ToString` in your query.

Comment: yes, using FirstOrDefault as suggested by you and KristoferA makes the linq query run faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(from acct in acctTest
where acct.AccountId == acctID
select acct.CustomerColl)
  .Where(c => c.CustomerId == custId)
  .Select(cn => cn.CustomerName)
  .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: apart from FirstOrDefault (replace tostring with firstordefault, how is the query execution different between your code and mine? I tried your piece of code, it ran way faster.

Comment: Because I start off by getting just the account you want, and then the customer. Your original sample query executes like the equivalent of a full outer join...

Also, in your loop example you forgot to break out of the outer loop, so even after you have assigned customerName it will keep looping through all the accounts.

Comment: You're welcome. Either way, the loop version will beat the L2S version performance wise (in the current framework version*) if you break out of both loops when you have found what you're looking for. But the linq version is nicer from a programming perspective; both to type and read.

* = maybe they will borrow ideas from the relational db side in future versions, so that L2O queries can do more complex joins, optimizations etc...

Answer (score 1):

The fourth execution looks like it hit garbage collection on the Linq side.

Other than that, LINQ doesn't know you're only trying to get a single instance of the customer name.  It doesn't know the relationship that CustomId or AccountIds are unique, which is what your code is assuming.  In short, the code isn't analogous :)

Also, in the first example, you might want to check in the outer loop if custerName != NULL so you can stop short ;)

Answer (score 1):

An obvious thing, looking at the code above is - In case of `foreach`, you are stopping the inner loop execution when **a** match is found for the customerID.

Whereas, it doesn't seem to be the case with LINQ.

Is the output of `foreach` and LINQ query same?
How about using a JOIN and using `FirstOrDefault`, as someone has suggested here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you identified your usage of LINQ as a bottleneck in your application? If not, it's unlikely you will and chasing microseconds between traditional foreach and lambdas is burning your valuable time for no real benefit. You will probably spend more time on one database call or I/O operation than you do in all the LINQ expressions combined. Worry about those instead.